# htaccess rewrite rules for directories

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am having trouble with some rewrite rules on an updated site...I am trying to redirect requests for old directories to new pages, like this:

http://www.mysite.com/olddirectory  --> http://www.mysite.com/this-is-the-new-page

the following rule works, but not with a trailing slash on the directory:
ie: /olddirectory redirects correctly, but /olddirectory/ doesn't

```
RewriteRule ^olddirectory$ this-is-the-new-page [R=301,NC,L]
```

Any ideas on how to get it to recognise the trailing slash on the dir?

Answer (score 1):

The following rule will do redirect with or without trailing slash:

```
RewriteRule ^olddirectory/?$ /this-is-the-new-page [NC,R=301,L]
```

The key is to make trailing slash optional, and that's what `?` does: `/?`